# SQL help in .NET WPF to retrieve multiple rows into DataGrid

Tags: c#, sql, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I'm making a program at work for people to retrieve gift card info.

I had a look around and there appears to be a few ways of doing this but I've not got one working yet. I'm trying to get some data for the history of a card (Multiple rows) out of a database and display it on a WPF form. I've changed the connection string and it used a variable `cardNumber` for the `where` clause. At the moment I've got the code posted below.

Edit: to clarify `ResultsGrid` is the Data Grid View on the UI

```
        if (CardNumber.TextLength == 14)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=USICOAL;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader reader;

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT STORE_NO, WORKSTATION_NO, RTL_TRN_NO, AMOUNT, ACCT_TRN_TYPE_CODE, ACCT_TRN_DATETIME, OLD_BALANCE, NEW_BALANCE FROM ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION WHERE ACCOUNT_NO = " + cardNumber;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

            sqlConnection1.Open();

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ResultsGrid.DataSource = reader;
            ResultsGrid.Refresh();

            sqlConnection1.Close();
        }
        //Else do nothing
        ...

        private void CardNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Try converting Value to int
            try
            {
                cardNumber = long.Parse(CardNumber.Text);
            } catch // Catch Exception thrown
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable To Convert to long");
                CardNumber.Text = cardNumber.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error the datagrid is just blank. ran debug and put a break in and can see that the reader has data in it.

Comment: remove the refresh line or do applcation.doevents()

Comment: Forgive my ignorance i'm new to .net could you elaborate on the doevent solution please.

Comment: it is the line of code which is ran automatically when ever a block of code is finished and returns to waiting on another event. in some cases you want to basically have changes which are made to the to the ui happen before then. eg if you update a textbox and then try to read from it before the control is returned to the ui then it will have the old value. i suggested it for testing purposes

Comment: Thanks i've done a bit of research online and it looks like it might do the trick. i'll give it a try at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try as below,  (between 
            sqlConnection1.Open(); and close();)

```
SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt=new DataTable("ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION");
da.Fill(dt);
ResultsGrid.ItemsSource=dt.Defaultview;
```

I recommend to write codes manually with automatic intellisense support by visual studio meaning don't just copy above code because it is case sensitive.

and you don't need 3 lines,

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
ResultsGrid.DataSource = reader;
ResultsGrid.Refresh();
```

Comment: And seems you need to pay attention to case sensitiveness. You have CardNumber and cardNumber.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. CardNumber is a UI text field. in another method i'm using cardNumber for validation. i'll put the mothod after the main one now

Comment: Changed the code as suggested but now in debug i'm seeing no data being retrieved. i'm still new to .net and using sql in it. i'm doing a bit more reading now but can you explain this line
DataTable dt=new DataTable("ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION");
how does the DataTable link to the Data Adapter?

Comment: It is defining the new DataTable will take the table structure of ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION as its (Data)Table structure automatically. On the other hand if we do manually, we have to name all columns to make structure by another way.

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanks for all your help it's working now. i'm new so my upvote doesn't display yet but you've goten them.

It now looks like this

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection();
sqlConnection1.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=###; Initial Catalog =USICOAL; Integrated Security=True";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT STORE_NO, WORKSTATION_NO, RTL_TRN_NO, AMOUNT, ACCT_TRN_TYPE_CODE, ACCT_TRN_DATETIME, OLD_BALANCE, NEW_BALANCE FROM ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION WHERE ACCOUNT_NO = " + cardNumber + "order by ACCT_TRN_DATETIME";

sqlConnection1.Open();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
ResultsGrid.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: congratulations ! I also upvoted your question. Have good day. :)